# Grunt - grunt-eslint does not start task

Tags: javascript, json, gruntjs, grunt-eslint

I've set up the [grunt-eslint](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-eslint) in my gruntfile.js, but when I run the "grunt eslint", nothing happens. The task looks like it would start but just stands still even after 15min.

All my other tasks works just fine, all except eslint which shows no errors or anything.

gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
   eslint: {
    options: {
      configFile: '.eslintrc.json'
    },
    target: ['src/js/*.js']
   },
  })

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-eslint');

  grunt.registerTask('eslint', [
    'eslint',
  ]);
}
```

.eslintrc.json

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true
  },
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "rules": {
    "indent": [
        "error",
        "tab"
    ],
    "linebreak-style": [
        "error",
        "windows"
    ],
    "quotes": [
        "error",
        "double"
    ],
    "semi": [
        "error",
        "always"
    ]
  }
}
```

Both the gruntfile and .eslintrc.json is in root

Does anyone know what it is that can cause this? Is my setup wrong?

Comment: Is your config file name correct? I mean in your configuration it looks like "eslintrc.json" but maybe actually it's ".eslintrc.json"?

Comment: Thanks for the correction, been trying different filenames. Even with ".eslintrc.json" it is the same thing, nothing happends

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

If you add --verbose option when running:

```
grunt eslint --verbose
```

You'll see that your task is running repeatedly - because you named your task eslint(which is the same name as already registered eslint task) grunt falls into infinite loop.

Change

```
 grunt.registerTask('eslint', [
    'eslint',
  ]);
```

to:

```
 grunt.registerTask('myeslinttask', [
    'eslint',
  ]);
```

and run:

```
grunt myeslinttask
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem of:

grunt.registerTask('eslint', [
    'eslint',
  ]);

is that it will call it self forever, just delete this registerTask command
and run grunt eslint , that will be enough to